# Potentiometer action in an audio mixer

Tags: operational-amplifier

[I found these schematics for an audio mixer.](https://sdiy.info/wiki/CGS_matrix_mixer_Eurorack)

I reproduce the mainpart of the schematics. A first stage of input buffers before each in line consisting of an opamp is not reproduced. I am only interested in unipolar mode.

[image]

I recognize a summing inverting op amp circuit. After the first op amp we have

$$
V = - \sum_i V_i \frac{1}{1 + R_i / 100k}
$$

Where \$R_i\$ is the resistance value of the i-th potentiometer.

If the potentiometer is on the far right, we then have a coefficient of \$1\$ in front of \$V_i\$. It is ok.

When you turn the potentiometer on the far left, for a potentiometer of 25k, you then have a coefficient of \$ \frac{1}{1 + 25k / 100k} = 0.8\$.

The documentation says:

> When in unipolar mode, all pots feeding that output behave in regular fashion, that is when the knob is fully counter-clockwise, no signal from the associated input passes into the mix. As the knob is advanced clockwise, a greater portion of the signal passes into the mix.

I don't understand how 80% of the signal can be considered no signal.

It seems that I am missing something.

Comment: Note that the schematics read "*  multiple decoupling caps, as needed".  You might get away with it as drawn, but I'd suggest adding (the pads at least) for 0.1µF caps near each TL072 + and - pin and ground.  That way, if it is built and squeals badly or generates high-frequency oscillations, just add the caps.

Comment: Do you mean decoupling capacitors between power supply pins and ground or between inverting and noninverting inputs and ground ?

Comment: Power supply and ground.  Adding caps to the inputs will essentially add a low-pass filter to the input and block all but the lowest audio signals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *I am only interested in unipolar mode.*

And

> *I don't understand how 80% of the signal can be considered as a no
> signal.*

That's because you have misread the circuit. When a wiper is fully counter-clockwise (unipolar mode), its associated input becomes grounded and hence, does not contribute any signal to the output of the op-amp mixer.

Comment: Indeed, i thought that it was connected to nothing and not to ground. Thanks Andy.